# Including a certain div with AngularJS on my html main file

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I'm starting with AngularJS and I know how to include a whole HTML document inside another HTML document, however I'd like to include only certain div.

I always used jQuery for this kind of things and I'm not sure if the logic is the same and I could target only "certain" parts of the remote document and not all of it.

My code is this but I don't know how to target with CSS selectors the specific div I'm interested in.

Main Document's relevant part looks like this, and the remote document would have a div with id #remote-div, but I don't know where to asses it:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://website.com/remote-document.html")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
  });
});

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: `<h1 ng-bind-html="myWelcome"></h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Use one way flow syntax property binding:

```
<div [innerHTML]="myWelcome"></div>
```